# C# Html Agility Pack, BrowserSession, CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. HTTP 403

Tags: c#, authentication, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to display information for a vessel in my C# application.

I am using the Html Agility Pack to scrape the web page.

But, in order to this, I first have to login. In order to log in I am using a BrowserSession class that takes care of the HttpWebRequest.

I then use a basic function to call the class. Unfortunately, the login does not work and I get a CSRF verification failed error.

This is my code:

```
private void LocateVessel()
{
BrowserSession b = new BrowserSession();
b.Get("https://www.fleetmon.com/users/login/");
string strToken = b.FormElements["csrfmiddlewaretoken"];
b.FormElements["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = strToken;
b.FormElements["next"] = "";
b.FormElements["username"] = "username";
b.FormElements["password"] = "password";
var response = b.Post("https://www.fleetmon.com/users/login/");
MessageBox.Show(response);
}

public class BrowserSession
{
private bool _isPost;
private bool _isDownload;
private HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument _htmlDoc;
private string _download;
public CookieContainer cookiePot;   //<- This is the new CookieContainer

public CookieCollection Cookies { get; set; }
public FormElementCollection FormElements { get; set; }
public string Get(string url)
{
_isPost = false;
CreateWebRequestObject().Load(url);
return _htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
}
public string Get2(string url)
{
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UseCookies = true;
web.PreRequest = new HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(OnPreRequest2);
web.PostResponse = new HtmlWeb.PostResponseHandler(OnAfterResponse2);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
}
public string Post(string url)
{
_isPost = true;
CreateWebRequestObject().Load(url, "POST");
return _htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
}
public string GetDownload(string url)
{
_isPost = false;
_isDownload = true;
CreateWebRequestObject().Load(url);
return _download;
}
private HtmlWeb CreateWebRequestObject()
{
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UseCookies = true;
web.PreRequest = new HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(OnPreRequest);
web.PostResponse = new HtmlWeb.PostResponseHandler(OnAfterResponse);
web.PreHandleDocument = new HtmlWeb.PreHandleDocumentHandler(OnPreHandleDocument);
return web;
}
protected bool OnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
{
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
AddCookiesTo(request);
if (_isPost) AddPostDataTo(request);
return true;
}
public bool OnPreRequest2(HttpWebRequest request)
{
request.CookieContainer = cookiePot;
return true;
}
protected void OnAfterResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
{
SaveCookiesFrom(response); 
}
protected void OnAfterResponse2(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
{
            //do nothing
}
protected void OnPreHandleDocument(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
{
SaveHtmlDocument(document);
}
private void AddPostDataTo(HttpWebRequest request){
string payload = FormElements.AssemblePostPayload();
byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.ToCharArray());
request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6";
request.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";
request.Referer = "http://www.fleetmon.com/";
request.UserAgent = "www.fleetmon.com";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.ContentLength = buff.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
System.IO.Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
}
private void AddCookiesTo(HttpWebRequest request)
{
if (Cookies != null && Cookies.Count > 0)
{
request.CookieContainer.Add(Cookies);
}
}
CookieCollection object
private void SaveCookiesFrom(HttpWebResponse response)
{
if ((response.Cookies.Count > 0))
{
if (Cookies == null)
{
Cookies = new CookieCollection();
}
Cookies.Add(response.Cookies);
}
}
private void SaveHtmlDocument(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
{
_htmlDoc = document;
FormElements = new FormElementCollection(_htmlDoc);
}
}
public class FormElementCollection : Dictionary<string, string>
{
public FormElementCollection(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc)
{
var inputs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input");
foreach (var element in inputs)
{
string name = element.GetAttributeValue("name", "undefined");
string value = element.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
if (!this.ContainsKey(name))
{
if (!name.Equals("undefined"))
{
Add(name, value);
}
}
}
}
public string AssemblePostPayload()
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var element in this)
{
string value = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(element.Value);
sb.Append("&" + element.Key + "=" + value);
}
return sb.ToString().Substring(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have AllowAutoRedirect set to False?